# Finding the homomorphisms $\Bbb Z / 6 \Bbb Z \to S_3 $

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have to find explicitly (i.e. as operated on the element of the domain) the homomorphisms (of groups) from $\Bbb Z / 6 \Bbb Z$ to $S_3$.

Comment: What've you tried?

Answer (score 3):

Let $G=\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ for simplicity. If $f\colon \mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}\to S_3$ is a homomorphism, then one of the following happens:

1. $\ker f=0\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}=\{0\}$
2. $\ker f=2\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}=2G$
3. $\ker f=3\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}=3G$
4. $\ker f=\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}=G$

Now recall that the image of $f$ is isomorphic to $G/\ker f$

Hint: you have no possibility for 1, three for 2, two for 3 and one for 4.

---

A seemingly different approach (it's actually the same, though).

If $f\colon G\to S_3$ is a homomorphism, then the image of $f$ is a cyclic subgroup of $S_3$ of order $1$, $2$, $3$ or $6$, because $G$ is cyclic and has subgroups of order $6$, $3$, $2$ and $1$ (one for each order).

Since $S_3$ has

1. one element of order $1$
2. three elements of order $2$
3. twe elements of order $3$
4. no element of order $6$

the total number of homomorphisms is $1+3+2=6$.

Comment: and if I want the homomorphism with ker of order 3?

Comment: @GiuliaB. That's case 3: the image of $f$ can be any subgroup of order $2$ in $S_3$.

Comment: when you write $ker f=3G$ what do you mean?

Comment: @GiuliaB. The image of multiplication by $3$, in this case $\{0,3\}$; so $3G$ has two elements and $G/3G$ has three. I had “case 3” instead of “case 2” in my previous comment, sorry.

Comment: can you be more clear using the classes [0],[1],....[6] and $S_3={1,(12),(13),(23),(123),(132)}$?How is the action of f?

Comment: @GiuliaB. Suppose we want a homomorphism in case 2; then $\ker f=\{[0],[2],[4]\}$ and so $f([0])=f([2])=f([4])$, $f([1])=f([3])=f([5])$. Of course $f([0])$ must be the identity, and $f([1])$ can be any of $(12)$, $(13)$ or $(23)$. So you have three homomorphism in case 2.

Comment: why $S_3$ has two cyclic subgroups of order 3?

Comment: @GiuliaB. Sorry again: it has two elements of order 3

Comment: so I have  one cyclic subgroup of order 3? the total number of homomorphism is 6?